# Leave-one-out performance variance on validation dataset

Tags: neural-networks, classification, cross-validation

I'm having good performance on leave-one-out validation (not leaving one out, leaving 2 out, one for each class) but when trying in my validation set, the performance is not that good, from 85% precision to 60%.

Context:
I read some of the answers made before but, I have some differents aboarding, I'm working on a dataset that's like a time-series. I'm trying to classify on binary tags, I tried on some algorithms like knn, svm, and decision trees, but none of it works, so we started trying on Neural Net (Keras) on this. I got that performance, on k-fold cross-validation, the curves of learning overfit quickly an loss validation breaks easily, don't know what else to try, any recommendations for the next post are welcome, thanks.

Some clarifications, my datasets arent so big having 300 samples and are not exactly balanced, so when overfit go straight to predict only one class, already try to balance the dataset and get better results

Answer (score 2):

Leave-One-Out validation doesn't work for time series data, because if your model has been trained on data from time $t-1$ and $t+1$ (that is, from both before and after the time point you're trying to predict), it has an unfair advantage when it comes to predicting the data at time $t$. This post looks like a good introduction to the problem: https://towardsdatascience.com/model-evaluation-in-time-series-forecasting-ae41993e267c

Comment: I'm not trying to predict a regression or a precise value of my time series, maybe i expressed my self bad, y more like an spectre, and im trying to detect similarity paterns on it thats why trying to clissify them